# how do i update dictionary in second for loop if type is not dict

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

```
dic={"a":1,
   "b":5,
   "c":{"a":3,"c":-5,"d":{"a":1,"b":3}}}
```

and output is

```
{"a":5,"b":8,"c":-5,"d":0}
```

i am facing updating dictionary in second for loop

```
d=dict()
d2=dict()
for i in dic:
    c_dict=dic[i]
    if type(dic[i])!=dict:              #a:1 ,b:5
        d[i] = dic[i]
    else:
        for j in c_dict:
            value=c_dict[j]
            if type(value)!=dict:
                d2[j]=value
```

d2[j]=value   for this i have to update with previous values of a and b

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: {"a":5,"b":8,"c":-5,"d":0}

Comment: [edit] your post and add that

Answer (score 0):

1. As you need to implement the same for multiple levels of a dict, you need a recursive method, handle a dict:

   - if the value is int, add it
   - if the value is dict, call the method on that value
2. As you want to do an addition with every value, you'd need to ensure there is a value before adding, you can solve that with a `defaultdict(int)` which will make sure there is always a zero for every key you ask, so you can directly do `+=`

```
from collections import defaultdict


def add_to_dict(base, more_values):
    for k, val in more_values.items():
        base[k] += 0  # for keys like 'd'
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            add_to_dict(base, val)
        else:
            base[k] += val


data = {"a": 1, "b": 5,
        "c": {"a": 3, "c": -5, "d": {"a": 1, "b": 3}}}

result = defaultdict(int)
add_to_dict(result, data)

print(result)  # {"a": 5, "b": 8, "c": -5, "d": 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question here is whether the *d* key should be in the resulting dictionary. If it's to be ignored then:

```
dic = {"a": 1,
       "b": 5,
       "c": {"a": 3, "c": -5, "d": {"a": 1, "b": 3}}}

result = {}

def process(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            process(v)
        else:
            result[k] = result.get(k, 0) + v

process(dic)

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 5, 'b': 8, 'c': -5}
```

**Note:**

Assumption here is that all values are either dictionary or numeric types